# how to link two docker containers?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, docker

I am new to docker.I built a crawler with headless chrome But Now I have to deploy with docker and there is image for https://github.com/yukinying/chrome-headless-browser-docker and it will host remote debugging mode in port 9222  and there is another container my node app is running I don't know how to link these both container .

```
docker run -it --name nodeserver --link  chrome:chrome nodeapp bash
```

But inside that docker I can't access the localhost:9222

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using docker-compose, it comes with docker for mac / windows and is made for this kind of simple connection.

You would need a docker compose file something like

```
version: "3"

services:
  headless-browser:
    image: yukinying/chrome-headless
    ports:
      - 9222

  crawler:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - headless-browser
```

And then a Docker file in the same folder
e.g. for testing connection use

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update && apk add curl

CMD curl http://headless-browser:9222
```

Use the command `docker-compose up`

Output would be the console page in text (so you know the connection is working ok)

To avoid any issues with indentation... I've made a repo to copy and paste from: https://github.com/TheSmokingGnu/stackOverflowAnswer

Comment: ```ERROR: In file '.\docker-compose.yml', service 'ports' must be a mapping not an array.``` it throws an error

Comment: I made an error with the indentation copy and pasting into SO.  I've updated above also made a repo if it messes up the indentation for you (see the answer)